# GLSL. Нормаль нулевой длины во фрагментном шейдере

Tags: c#, opengl, шейдеры, glsl, opentk

Пишу на C# с использованием OpenTK v.3.2.0

Шейдеры из уроков https://learnopengl.com
портированные для OpenTK https://github.com/opentk/LearnOpenTK/tree/master/Chapter2/4-LightingMaps

[image: скриншот]
Маленький кубик - положение источника света

**Из вершинного во фрагментный шейдер попадает нормаль нулевой длины.**
**После этой операции:**

```
Normal = aNormal * mat3(transpose(inverse(model)));
```

**Почему так происходит?**

Вершинный шейдер:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 aPosition;
in vec3 aNormal;
in vec2 aTexture;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 Position;
out vec2 Texture;

void main(void)
{
    Position = vec3(vec4(aPosition, 1.0) * model);
    Normal = aNormal * mat3(transpose(inverse(model)));
    Texture = aTexture;

    gl_Position = vec4(Position, 1.0) * view * projection;
}
```

Фрагментный шейдер:

```
#version 330

struct Material {
    sampler2D diffuse;
    sampler2D specular;
    float     shininess;
};

struct Light {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

uniform Light light;
uniform Material material;
uniform vec3 viewPosition;

out vec4 outputColor;

in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 Position;
in vec2 Texture;

uniform sampler2D texture0;

void main()
{
    // ambient
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, Texture));

    // Diffuse 
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - Position);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * texture(material.diffuse, Texture).rgb;

    // Specular
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPosition - Position);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * texture(material.specular, Texture).rgb;

    vec3 resultColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;

    outputColor = vec4(resultColor, 1.0);
}
```

Ну и собственно класс объекта, на котором я это все тесктирую:

```
using System;

using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;

using RUTClient.Core.Helpers;
using RUTClient.Core.Shaders;
using RUTClient.Core.Output;
using OpenTK.Input;

namespace RUTClient.Core.Primitive
{
    class Primitive
    {
        protected float[] vertices;
        protected int vertexBuffer;
        protected int vertexArray;
        protected int vertexLength;
        protected Texture diffuse, specular;
        protected Vector2 size;
        protected Vector3 position;
        protected float angle;
        protected Vector3 scale;

        protected Matrix4 rotationMatrix;
        protected Matrix4 scaleMatrix;
        protected Matrix4 translationMatrix;
        protected Matrix4 modelMatrix;

        protected bool Visible = true;

        public virtual void Initialize(Vector2 size, Vector3 startPosition)
        {
            this.size = size;

            angle = 0.0f;
            scale = Vector3.One;
            position = new Vector3(startPosition.X, -startPosition.Y, startPosition.Z);

            vertices = new float[] {
                // Positions          Normals              Texture coords

                // front
                -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //lb
                 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, //rb
                 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //ru
                 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //ru
                -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //lu
                -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //lb
                // back
                 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //ru
                 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, //rb
                -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //lb
                -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //lb
                -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //lu
                 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //ru
                // right
                +0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //lb
                +0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, //rb
                +0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //ru
                +0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //ru
                +0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //lu
                +0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //lb
                // left
                -0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //ru
                -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, //rb
                -0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //lb
                -0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //lb
                -0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //lu
                -0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //ru
                // up
                -0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //lb
                +0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, //rb
                +0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //ru
                +0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //ru
                -0.5f, +0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //lu
                -0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //lb
                // down
                +0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //ru
                +0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, //rb
                -0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //lb
                -0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //lb
                -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //lu
                +0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, //ru
            };

            vertexLength = 8;

            rotationMatrix = Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(angle));
            scaleMatrix = Matrix4.CreateScale(scale);
            translationMatrix = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(position);

            //modelMatrix = Matrix4.Identity *
            //    translationMatrix *
            //    rotationMatrix *
            //    scaleMatrix;
            modelMatrix = Matrix4.Identity;

            vertexBuffer = GL.GenBuffer();
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexBuffer);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertices.Length * sizeof(float), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            vertexArray = GL.GenVertexArray();
            GL.BindVertexArray(vertexArray);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexBuffer);

            int vertexLocation = ShaderManager.guiShader.GetAttribLocation("aPosition");
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocation);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, vertexLength * sizeof(float), 0);

            int normalLocation = ShaderManager.guiShader.GetAttribLocation("aNormal");
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(normalLocation);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(normalLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, vertexLength * sizeof(float), 3 * sizeof(float));

            int texCoordLocation = ShaderManager.guiShader.GetAttribLocation("aTexCoord");
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, vertexLength * sizeof(float), 6 * sizeof(float));
        }

        public virtual void WindowResize(int width, int height)
        {
            Initialize(new Vector2(width, height), position);
        }

        public virtual void Update(double time)
        {
            angle -= 20.0f * (float)time;
            rotationMatrix =
                Matrix4.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(angle * 1.0f)) *
                Matrix4.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(angle * 1.0f)) *
                Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(angle * 1.0f));

            //modelMatrix = Matrix4.Identity * translationMatrix * rotationMatrix * scaleMatrix;
            modelMatrix = Matrix4.Identity;

            KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();
            float lightSpeed = 1.0f * (float)time;

            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Key.Left))
            {
                lightPos.X -= lightSpeed;
            }
            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Key.Right))
            {
                lightPos.X += lightSpeed;
            }
            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Key.Up))
            {
                lightPos.Y += lightSpeed;
            }
            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Key.Down))
            {
                lightPos.Y -= lightSpeed;
            }
        }

        private Vector3 lightPos = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f);
        public virtual void Draw(double time)
        {
            if (Visible)
            {
                GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

                GL.BindVertexArray(vertexArray);
                
                diffuse.Use(TextureUnit.Texture0);
                specular.Use(TextureUnit.Texture1);
                
                ShaderManager.objectShader.Use();

                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetMatrix4("model", modelMatrix);
                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetMatrix4("view", CameraManager.Perspective.GetViewMatrix());
                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetMatrix4("projection", CameraManager.Perspective.GetProjectionMatrix());

                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetVector3("viewPosition", CameraManager.Perspective.Position);

                // Here we specify to the shaders what textures they should refer to when we want to get the positions.

                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetVector3("light.position", lightPos);
                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetVector3("light.ambient", new Vector3(0.1f));
                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetVector3("light.diffuse", new Vector3(10.5f));
                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetVector3("light.specular", new Vector3(1.0f));

                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetInt("material.diffuse", 0);
                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetInt("material.specular", 1);
                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetFloat("material.shininess", 32.0f);

                GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, vertices.Length / vertexLength);

                GL.BindVertexArray(vertexArray);
                ShaderManager.objectShader.Use();
                
                Matrix4 lampMatrix = Matrix4.Identity;
                lampMatrix *= Matrix4.CreateScale(0.025f);
                lampMatrix *= Matrix4.CreateTranslation(lightPos);

                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetMatrix4("model", lampMatrix);
                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetMatrix4("view", CameraManager.Perspective.GetViewMatrix());
                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetMatrix4("projection", CameraManager.Perspective.GetProjectionMatrix());
                ShaderManager.objectShader.SetVector3("light.ambient", new Vector3(1.0f));
                GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, vertices.Length / vertexLength);

                if (GL.GetError() != ErrorCode.NoError)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(GL.GetError());
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            GL.DeleteBuffer(vertexBuffer);
            GL.DeleteVertexArray(vertexArray);
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            Visible = true;
        }

        public void Hide()
        {
            Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Из установленных флагов **glEnable()** имеется только **CullFace** и **DepthTest**, остальное по-умолчанию.

Comment: Сформулируйте полноценный вопрос в конце поста, а то сложно докрутив до низа понять, что же требовалось изначально. В вашем вопросе нет ни одного знака вопроса.

Comment: @aepot Так лучше?

Comment: Не особо, напишите развернуто, в чем проблема, какой хотите получить результат, и задайте конкретный вопрос, чтобы на него можно было получить конкретный ответ, который вы ожидаете. "Что я сделал не так?", это вам могут в комментариях советов накидать, а ответ вы не получите. Я сам вам помочь с ответом не могу, потому что GL - не по моей части.

Comment: @aepot переделал вопрос, удалось сузить вопрос до конкретного момента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка из-за невнимательности.
И не одна.

1.
В вершинном шейдере используется

```
in vec2 aTexture;
```

а атрибут вызывается

```
int texCoordLocation = ShaderManager.guiShader.GetAttribLocation("aTexCoord");
```

2. 

Атрибут вызывался у неверного шейдера. Нужно было использовать другой.
В моем случае:

```
int texCoordLocation = ShaderManager.objectShader.GetAttribLocation("aTexture");
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]